# Counting Problem: Extended Combination

Tags: combinatorics

**The Original Question:** A personnel director for a corporation has hired ten new engineers. If three (distinctly different) positions are open at a Cleveland plant, in how many ways can she fill the positions?

**My Interpretation of The Question:** Here we have set of 10 engineers (all of whom are already hired and must be put to work in some position in the Cleveland plant), and and we have 3 different position/jobs in which we can place each of them. We are not given any limits on how many engineers can be put to work in each position. So, we could put them all into one position and none of them into the other two positions and so on.

**What I have done so far:** The book gave us a counting principle as follows:

The number of ways of partitioning $n$
  distinct objects into $k$
  distinct groups containing $n_{1},n_{2},...,n_{k}$
  objects in each group so that $\sum_{i=1}^{k}n_{k}=n$
 , is given by 
$$\frac{n!}{n_{1}!n_{2}!\cdot\cdot\cdot n_{k}!}$$
 So, I the problem resembles the following summation
$$\frac{10!}{10!0!0!}+\frac{10!}{9!1!0!}+\frac{10!}{8!2!0!}+...+\frac{10!}{0!10!0!}+\frac{10!}{0!9!1!}+\frac{10!}{0!8!2!}+\cdot\cdot\cdot+\frac{10!}{0!0!10!}+P_{3}^{10}\text{other terms}$$
 (I am not so sure how many other remaining terms there are).

**What I Need Help With:**
I think I am looking at this question the wrong way, any ideas? Also, if I am not wrong, is there a better way of counting what I am trying to count above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that you put $n_1$ of them into position $1$, $n_2$ into position $2$, and $n_3$ into position $3$; then $n_1,n_2$, and $n_3$ must be non-negative integers satisfying the equation $n_1+n_2+n_3=10$, and every triple $\langle n_1,n_2,n_3\rangle$ of non-negative integers satisfying that equation corresponds to an acceptable assignment of the engineers to positions. Thus, you really just want to count the solutions to that equation. This is a standard [stars-and-bars problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29); at the link you’ll find both a formula and a pretty decent explanation of where the formula comes from, i.e., of the reasoning that you can use to see why it solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I actually know exactly what you  are talking about, we did these kind of problems in my discrete mathematics course. My perspective was way off, thanks for getting me back on track.

Comment: @Jimmy: You’re welcome! Yes, that’s a standard topic in most discrete math courses, so you should be in good shape now.

Answer (score 2):

Brian's solution is assuming the engineers are indistinguishable. There are other possible interpretations. If the engineers are not robots, but unique individuals, you can argue like this:

Each of the ten (distinct) engineers can get one of three possible positions. In other words there are
$$3\cdot3\cdots3 =3^{10}$$
ways to put them to work.

Comment: If we sent all of the workers to one job, this is only one way to fill the positions. Would your method count this as 10 ways or one way? Because we don't want to distinguish something which computer each engineer gets once we have assigned them the job.

Answer (score 2):

Interpreting the word problem in order to get to the math problem: usually, a "position" is filled by one person.  Specifying the "Cleveland plant" implies that there are other plants in other locations for the other engineers. So the problem reduces to finding the number of permutations of $3$ distinct objects selected from $10$.

Comment: I agree with this! I will put both assumptions. You know I once heard a joke a about a physicist, a mathematician, and an economist about how to open a can of soup while stranded on a desolate island. The economist assumes that he has a can opener. Its funny but, it is so important to clarify your assumption when you write an problem in a written language.